# Google Data Studio - Calculting Two Same name Fields in Two Different Data Sources

Tags: google-data-studio

I am using Data Studio to do a Report on two Data Sources: `Income` and `Expenses`. These data sources have the same field names and each one of them has a scorecard to sum each of their values in the `Amount` field.

I am now trying to create a third Scorecard called `Profit` (Income - Expenses) but run into a problem with trying to calculate the Amount Field. When I click on the two Score Cards for Income and Amount then blend the data, I get a defaulted percentage calculation (Income / Expenses):

[image]

But when I go to change the operator from `/` to `-`, it will instead take the difference of the Amount field from the same Data Source and return it as 0.

[image]

Is there a way I can figure out the difference between these two same-named fields when referencing two data sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this thanks to a user on the [Data Studio Community Forums](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/14205420?hl=en&msgid=26287794). I will summarize for those looking for a similar answer.

As of writing this, Data Studio has no way to refer to a blended data fields by their data sources, if blending 2 data sources together you will need to give them unique identifiers. Luckily, the data studio has the ability to rename metrics and dimensions for blended data without having to change any field names in your data sources. Once you create the blended data you want to perform the following steps:

1. Go to **Resource > Manage Blended Data**
2. Click on **Edit** for your newly created blended data
3. Hover over each metric/dimension and click the **Pencil Icon** to edit
4. Rename your metric(In my case I called them `Income(Amount)` and `Expense(Amount)`

You will now be able to modify the calculated fields as you please.